# How select rows with grouping by month

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How select rows grouping by month.
So I have an entity:

```
public class Security
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Quatation { get; set; }

    public SecurityType SecurityType { get; set; }

    public double Denomination { get; set; }

    public CurrencyType DemoniationType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ReportPeriod> ReportPeriods { get; set; }
}
```

Report Period entity:

```
 public class ReportPeriod
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public Guid SecurityId { get; set; }

    public Guid StockExchangeId { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Security Security { get; set; }
}
```

So I need somehow get general Amount by every month in a year for ReportPeriod. Does anyone have some ideas how to do it?

Comment: Does the `Start` and `End` properties represent the month start and month end date respectively (like 2018-01-01 00:00:00 & 2018-01-31 23:59:59)?

Comment: @user1672994 No it can be range of 2-3 days for example. And somehow i needs to for collection like for January: *** amount

Comment: @Jorge range of start and end can go across the month ?

Comment: the lazy (and technically not correct) alternative could be to group by month of the average of the 2 dates if they are only few days apart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by using LINQ. Please find the below code snippet in C#. Hope it helps. Here we are grouping by year and month and then summing up the amount as well.

```
namespace Solutions
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Security
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Quatation { get; set; }

        //public SecurityType SecurityType { get; set; }

        public double Denomination { get; set; }

        //public CurrencyType DemoniationType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ReportPeriod> ReportPeriods { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReportPeriod
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        public Guid SecurityId { get; set; }

        public Guid StockExchangeId { get; set; }

        public double Amount { get; set; }

        public virtual Security Security { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entities
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Security security = new Security()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Denomination = 1,
                Name = "A",
                Quatation = "Z",
                ReportPeriods = new List<ReportPeriod>()
            };
            security.ReportPeriods.Add(new ReportPeriod()
            {
                Amount = 10,
                Security = security,
                SecurityId = security.Id,
                End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                Start = DateTime.Now,
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                StockExchangeId = Guid.NewGuid()
            });
            security.ReportPeriods.Add(new ReportPeriod()
            {
                Amount = 5,
                Security = security,
                SecurityId = security.Id,
                End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                Start = DateTime.Now,
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                StockExchangeId = Guid.NewGuid()
            });
            security.ReportPeriods.Add(new ReportPeriod()
            {
                Amount = 5,
                Security = security,
                SecurityId = security.Id,
                End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                Start = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                StockExchangeId = Guid.NewGuid()
            });

            foreach (var groupedReportValues in security.ReportPeriods
                .GroupBy(period => new { period.Start.Year, period.Start.Month }).Select(
                    groupedOnMonth => new
                    {
                        StartYear = groupedOnMonth.Key.Year,
                        StartMonth = groupedOnMonth.Key.Month,
                        AmountSum = groupedOnMonth.Sum(reportValue => reportValue.Amount)
                    }))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(groupedReportValues.StartYear);
                Console.WriteLine(groupedReportValues.StartMonth);
                Console.WriteLine(groupedReportValues.AmountSum);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently, I have assumed we need the data based on StartDate and added the grouping logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you want general Amount of month.

- Assuming you want it in the format `Dictionary<DateTime, double>` where `Key` is first date of Month (of which month we have general amount in `Value`).
- Assuming that, range of `start` and `end` doesn't go across the month.

Add this property in your `Security` class.

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, double> AmountGroupedByMonth
{
  get
  {
     Dictionary<DateTime, double> table = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();

     if (ReportPeriods != null && ReportPeriods.Count > 0)
     {
         ReportPeriod frtReportPeriod = ReportPeriods.First();

         DateTime monthStDt = 
             new DateTime(frtReportPeriod.Start.Year, frtReportPeriod.Start.Month, 1);
         double groupedAmount = 0;

         foreach (ReportPeriod reportPeriod in ReportPeriods)
         {
             //Checking if this report should be grouped with pervious report or not
             if (monthStDt.Year == reportPeriod.Start.Year 
                 && monthStDt.Month == reportPeriod.Start.Month)
             {
                 groupedAmount += reportPeriod.Amount;
             }
             else
             {
                 //if we find that this report is of different month.
                 table.Add(monthStDt, groupedAmount);

                 groupedAmount = reportPeriod.Amount;
                 monthStDt = 
                     new DateTime(reportPeriod.Start.Year, reportPeriod.Start.Month, 1);
             }
         }
         if (groupedAmount != 0 && !table.ContainsKey(monthStDt))
              table.Add(monthStDt, groupedAmount);
     }
     return table;
  }
}
```

by adding this property, Month wise grouped data will be easily available to the object of `Security` . and also, as it not stored in any variable, you will not be required to update it (or generate) before using it. Simply call this property and it will calculate general Amount month wise with latest available data.

```
Security s = new Security();

DateTime nowDate = DateTime.Now;
s.ReportPeriods = new List<ReportPeriod>();
for(int i = 0; i <= 70; i = i + 5)
{
  s.ReportPeriods.Add(new ReportPeriod(nowDate.AddDays(i), nowDate.AddDays( i + 3), 200 ));
}

Dictionary<DateTime, double> AmountGroupedByMonth = s.AmountGroupedByMonth;
```

And output will be like:

[image]